# First and last element connected

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

My problem is that I try to plot data with the matplotlib and it connects the first and the last data point. I am using python27 and Windows 7. My problem is just to big to show complete so I just show some parts of the source code. The plot function is as below:

```
def plot(x, aw,temperature):
    plt.clf()
    temperatureplot = plt.subplot(211)
    awplot = plt.subplot(212)
    
    temperatureplot.grid()
    awplot.grid()  

    #set subplots
    awplot.set_ylabel('water activity aw')
    awplot.plot(x,aw)
    awplot.margins(y=0.05) #adds a gap between maximum value and edge of diagram
    temperatureplot.set_ylabel('Temperature in degree C')
    temperatureplot.plot(x,temperature)
    temperatureplot.margins(y=0.05)
    
    awplot.set_xlabel('Time in [hm]')
    plt.gcf().canvas.draw()
```

I am using this, because I am plotting this in a Tkinter Gui and want to refresh it sometimes. The plot looks like:
[image]

My values are:

```
t = [161000, 161015...., 191115]
aw = [0.618,......, 0.532]
temperature = [23.7,....,24.4]
```

Is it a problem that I do not start with zero in the t array?

Comment: For the person whom down-voted, please could you explain why you did so, to improve my future posts and to maybe extend the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plot is processing the vectors in strict order, drawing a line from first coordinate to second and so on. But a circular buffer can start with lowest time at any point.

Thus the plot will often start somewhere in the middle of the plot window with nice incrementing time. Then it reaches the insertion point and jumps *back* in time to the start of the window -- drawing an ugly line -- then resuming up to the starting point.

The quick solution was replacing this line:

```
plot(pTime, pPos)
```

with two lines plotting each half in the right order:

```
plot(pTime[ptr:], pPos[ptr:])
plot(pTime[0:ptr], pPos[0:ptr])
```

Answer (score 6):

Pyplot is connecting the first (x,y) point with the second (x,y) point, with the third and so on... so it looks like there may be a (duplicate?) low value hidden towards the end of your `x`.

You can try `x == sorted(x)` to double check if your list is strictly ascending. It will return `False` if it's not.

You will probably want to find the (x,y) pair before you call your `plot()` function.

Comment: So `x==sorted(x)` returns `True`?

Comment: sorry for the delay, but yes it returns true, the weird thing is now I just plot another file and it connects the first point with a point somewhere in the middle. But I don't understand why, because the time array is just a list of numbers in a row and the other values are just measured?

Comment: You'd have to post a working example with some data; your code looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution I found was in the .txt file where my data was stored. The data set existed twice in the file and therefor caused the connection of start and endpoint by matplotlib.

Removing double data and the graph plotted properly. Fortunately, the two datasets appeared one after the other. So it was easy to delete the first part.

Since it was a huge data collection in my case, this was not obvious and therefor took some time to realise.

The problem was caused in creating the txt-file.