# Matplotlib connects end of data after animation refreshes

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm having an issue exactly like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016764/python27-matplotlib-first-and-last-element-connected) post, but slightly more frustrating.

I'm using matplotlib to read from a file that is being fed data from another application. For some reason, the ends of the data only connect after the animation (`animation.FuncAnimation`) has completed its first refresh. Here are some images:

This is before the refresh:
[image: Pre-Refresh]

And this is after the refresh:
[image: Post-Refresh]

Any ideas as to why this could be happening? Here is my code:

```
import json
import itertools
import dateutil.parser

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
import scipy.signal as sig
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

sensors = {}
data = []
lastLineReadNum = 0

class Sensor:

    def __init__(self, name, points = 0, lastReading = 0):
        self.points = points
        self.lastReading = lastReading
        self.name = name
        self.x = []
        self.y = []

class ScanResult:
    def __init__(self, name, id, rssi, macs, time):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.rssi = rssi
        self.macs = macs
        # Is not an integer, but a datetime.datetime
        self.time = time

def readJSONFile(filepath):

    with open(filepath, "r") as read_file:
        global lastLineReadNum
        # Load json results into an object that holds important info
        for line in itertools.islice(read_file, lastLineReadNum, None):
            temp = json.loads(line)
            # Only reads the most recent points...
            data.append(ScanResult(name = temp["dev_id"], 
                            id = temp["hardware_serial"], 
                            rssi = temp["payload_fields"]["rssis"],
                            macs = temp["payload_fields"]["macs"],
                            time = dateutil.parser.parse(temp["metadata"]["time"])))
            lastLineReadNum += 1

        return data

style.use('fivethirtyeight')
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

def smooth(y, box_pts):
    box = np.ones(box_pts)/box_pts
    y_smooth = np.convolve(y, box, mode='same')
    return y_smooth

def determineClosestSensor():
    global sensors

    #sensors.append(Sensor(time = xs3, rssi = ys3))

def determineXAxisTime(scanresult):
    return ((scanresult.time.hour * 3600) + (scanresult.time.minute * 60) + (scanresult.time.second)) / 1000.0

def animate(i):
    data = readJSONFile(filepath = "C:/python_testing/rssi_logging_json.json")

    for scan in data:
        sensor = sensors.get(scan.name)

        # First time seeing the sensor
        if(sensor == None):
            sensors[scan.name] = Sensor(scan.name)
            sensor = sensors.get(scan.name)
            sensor.name = scan.name
            sensor.x.append(determineXAxisTime(scan))
            sensor.y.append(scan.rssi)

        else:
            sensor.x.append(determineXAxisTime(scan))
            sensor.y.append(scan.rssi)

    ax1.clear()

    #basic smoothing using nearby averages

    #y_smooth3 = smooth(np.ndarray.flatten(np.asarray(sensors.get("sentrius_sensor_3").y)), 1)

    for graphItem in sensors.itervalues():
        smoothed = smooth(np.ndarray.flatten(np.asarray(graphItem.y)), 1)
        ax1.plot(graphItem.x, smoothed, label = graphItem.name, linewidth = 2.0)

    ax1.legend()

    determineClosestSensor()

    fig.suptitle("Live RSSI Graph from Sentrius Sensors", fontsize = 14)


def main():
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval = 15000)

    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Minor note: the name of the library is matplotlib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell you are regenerating your data in each animation step by appending to the existing datasets, but then this means that your last `x` point from the first step is followed by the first `x` point in the second step, leading to a rewind in the plot. This appears as the line connecting the last datapoint with the first one; the rest of the data is unchanged.

The relevant part of `animate`:

```
def animate(i):
    data = readJSONFile(filepath = "C:/python_testing/rssi_logging_json.json")

    for scan in data:
        sensor = sensors.get(scan.name)

        # First time seeing the sensor
        if(sensor is None): # always check for None with `is`!
            ... # stuff here    
        else:
            sensor.x.append(determineXAxisTime(scan)) # always append!
            sensor.y.append(scan.rssi)                # always append!

    ... # rest of the stuff here
```

So, in each animation step you
  1. load the same JSON file
  2. append the same data to an existing sensor identified by `sensors.get(scan.name)`
  3. plot stuff without ever using `i`.

Firstly, your `animate` should naturally make use of the index `i`: you're trying to do something concerning step `i`. I can't see `i` being used anywhere.

Secondly, your `animate` should be as lightweigh as possible in order to get a smooth animation. Load your data once before plotting, and only handle the drawing differences in `animate`. This will involve slicing or manipulating your data as a function of `i`.

Of course if the file really does change from step to step, and this is the actual dynamics in the animation (i.e. `i` is a dummy variable that is never used), all you need to do is zero-initialize all the plotting data in each step. Start with a clean slate. Then you'll stop seeing the lines corresponding to these artificial jumps in the data. But again, if you want a lightweigh `animate`, you should look into manipulating the underlying data of existing plots rather than replotting everything all the time (especially since calls to `ax1.plot` will keep earlier points on the canvas, which is not what you usually want in an animation).

Answer (score 0):

try changing :

```
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval = 15000)
```

to :

```
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval = 15000, repeat = False)
```